# How long do removed campaigns return in an api call?

Tags: google-ads, api

I'm wondering how long campaigns that have been removed return in the [CampainService.get()](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201607/CampaignService#get) call? The documentation does not list anything that says they would stop showing after a certain period but I am experiencing something that would say otherwise for accounts that I have not pulled in a while with the API.

Note: this was moved from StackOverflow